# Routing in Flask application

Tags: python, flask, routes

I am facing a routing problem in my flask application.

The routes are defined as below

```
@app.route("/<lang>/books/<name>.html")
def func1(lang="en", name="")
    pass

@app.route("/<lang>/books/index.html")
def func2(lang="en"):
    pass
```

So, if a url is requested like /en/books/index.html - it should route to 2nd function, but flask routes it to first function.

Why it is so?? I also changed the order of code by placing func2 above to func1 and still facing the same issue, can i know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
@app.route("/<lang>/books/<name>.html")
def func1(lang="en", name=""):

   if name == "index":
        return index()

   return something_else()
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought to implement the above one as i already did it, but this is not the right one. Why can't we just route to separate function as the endpoint to the route is more specific than the generic one.

Comment: @IronFist, because I don't want to do additional check inside the second function and call the first one. What if we had more url on top eg: @app.route("/category/index.html")  @app.route("/<lang>/books/<name>.html") - in this case I should not check only name == "index" , as I want to execute func1 and not to call index function

Comment: @RinsenS why would you route `/category/index.html` to the same place as `/<lang>/books/<name>.html`? I think this would confuse users quite a bit

Comment: @jprockbelly - The above namings are just examples, what if we have url's on top of func1 for which this function should execute - eg: /category/index.html or /news/index.html so check name == "index" will not work in all cases, right. can you pls help on resolving the above issues

Comment: @RinsenS - I suggest you don't do that. A better approach would be `/<basename>/index.html` you can then use `basename` to return the correct content. If these are just example then they are bad ones. Post the URLs you actually want and we can suggest a solution

Comment: @jprockbelly - Yes that's the better way /<basename>/index.html but for some base name which should not call the index func - so we need to add one more condition in the if like if name == "index" and basename == books right, because we want to execute func2 for other basenames, sorry I will not be able to share the company codes here

Comment: If you want to stick to what you want, then this is the correct answer. :)